# Passing route parameter to reducer method in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using routes with react-router as below

```
<Route path="product/:id" component={Product}/>
```

I am having component product as below code as below

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-async-connect';
import {load, isLoaded} from 'redux/modules/viewlodging';

@asyncConnect([{
    promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState } }) => {
       const promises = [];
       if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
           promises.push(dispatch(load()));
       }
       return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}])

@connect(
    state => ({viewdata: state.viewlodging.data}),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({load}, dispatch)
)

export default class Product extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        viewdata: PropTypes.object,
        location: PropTypes.object,
        load: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.routeParams.id); // here I get routeparameter
        const { viewdata } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Sample test</div>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
                <Viewfootertext viewdata={viewdata}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to pass parameter id to reducer method load, How to pass route parameter here in correct way?

Comment: any views here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@asyncConnect([{
    promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState }, params: { id }, }) => {
    const promises = [];
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
    promises.push(dispatch(load(id)));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
}])
```

Passing id with params worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can send it in either `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()`. Don't send it in `render` method since it fires every time you have new props or state changes.

you can access `route` `params` from `this.props.params`.

So try like this in your `container`

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const {id} = this.props.params;
    this.props.load(id); //you can send params values after component get mounted.
  }
```

And your container will look something like this

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {asyncConnect} from 'redux-async-connect';
import {load, isLoaded} from 'redux/modules/viewlodging';
@asyncConnect([{
  promise: ({
    store: {
      dispatch,
      getState
    }
  }) => {
    const promises = [];
    if (!isLoaded(getState())) {
      promises.push(dispatch(load()));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
}])

@connect(
  state => ({
    viewdata: state.viewlodging.data
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    load
  }, dispatch)
)

export default class Product extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    viewdata: PropTypes.object,
    location: PropTypes.object,
    load: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const {id} = this.props.params;
    this.props.load(id); //you can send params values after component get mounted.
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.routeParams.id); // here I get routeparameter
    //don't send in render method, since it'll be called many times
    const {
      viewdata
    } = this.props;
    return ( < div >
      < div > Sample test < /div> < /div> < Footer / >
      < Viewfootertext viewdata = {
        viewdata
      }
      /> < /div>
    );
  }
}
```